# What is causing my rsyslog timezone offset and / or time to be incorrect?

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I have a central logging server running rsyslog 7.x on RHEL 6

The logs are coming in with a UTC time but an EST offset for a device.

Here are some relevant configs.

`$template TEMPLATE_NAME,"%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %fromhost% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"`

`[root@host ]# hwclock
Thu 14 Feb 2019 05:35:25 PM EST  -0.877530 seconds
[root@host ]# date -u
Thu Feb 14 22:35:28 UTC 2019
[root@host ]# date
Thu Feb 14 17:35:29 EST 2019
[root@host ]#`

When I change the localtime to UTC and restart rsyslogd then the offset goes to +00:00  but when the localtime is in EST as it is now, only the offset changes to -05:00  but the time stamp would stay the same.

My goal is to have the logs reflect the local time with the proper offset.

So for a log written  at  3PM EST my current outcome is 
`2019-02-14T20:49:31-05:00`
But i would expect 
`2019-02-14T15:49:31-05:00`

Can someone please explain how to achieve this or why I am seeing what I am ?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities.. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the receiving time("timegenerated") instead of the reporting time("TIMESTAMP")?

```
$template TEMPLATE_NAME,"%timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %fromhost% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
```

Comment: I'll try this and get back.